# How can I downsample mesh3d object in R?

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I have a very high-resolution mesh in ply format. I read it to mesh3d object in R., However, after saving it to svg, the size of the plot is way too big. How can I downsample my `mesh3d` file so it consists only of a smaller number of nodes and triangles?

Comment: You need to describe what kind of downsampling you want to do, and give an example mesh for people to work with.

Comment: Take `Rvcg::vcgQEdecim`, `Rvcg::vcgIsotropicRemeshing`, or perhaps `vcgSample`, examples on `humface` playing around with parameters, and testing output with  `nfaces`, `nverts`and its potential output to see if they are directions that is useful to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, as @Chris suggested the best way to go is:

```
Rvcg::vcgQEdecim(mesh, percent = 0.05)
```